# Is it possible for a button to change its onClick information in different events

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, show-hide

I am looking for a javascript that will allow the images/characters to show different information depending on what chapter they are in when they are clicked .  For instance, in chapter one I want character A to show information A.  But in chapter 2 I want character A to show information B.  Here is the current code that I have:

HTML:

```
//Chapters/Events where characters move. Need info to change on chapter move
<a href="#" onclick= "chapter1();">1-prologue</a>
<a href="#" onclick= "chapter2();">2</a>
<a href="#" onclick= "chapter3();">3</a>

//Characters moving on map that are onClick buttons to show info
<a href="#">
<img id="tyrion-map" src="sm_tyrion.png" /></a>
<a href="#">
<img id="catelyn-map" src="purple-small.png" /></a>
<a href="#">
<img id="bran-map" src="yello-small.png" /></a>
```

JS:

```
//tyrion
var tyrion = null;

//catelyn
var catelyn = null;

//bran
var bran = null;

function init(){

    "use strict"; 

    tyrion = document.getElementById("tyrion-map");
    tyrion.style.position= 'relative'; 
    tyrion.style.left = '50px';
    tyrion.style.top = '50px';

    catelyn = document.getElementById("catelyn-map");
    catelyn.style.position= 'relative'; 
    catelyn.style.left = '50px'; 
    catelyn.style.top = '50px';

    bran = document.getElementById("bran-map");
    bran.style.position= 'relative'; 
    bran.style.left = '50px'; 
    bran.style.top = '50px';
```

}

```
//Chapter 1- prologue
function chapter1() {

    "use strict"; 

    tyrion1();
    catelyn1();
    prologue1();
    dany1();
    bran1();
    jon1();
    eddard1();
    arya1();
    sansa1();
}   


//Chapter 2
function chapter2() {

    "use strict"; 

    tyrion2();
    catelyn2();
    dany1();
    bran2();
    jon2();
    eddard2();
    arya1();
    sansa1();
    prologue2();
}


//Chapter 3
function chapter3() {

    "use strict"; 

    tyrion3();
    catelyn1();
    dany1();
    bran3();
    jon3();
    eddard3();
    arya1();
    sansa1();
    prologue2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact context/chapter thing, but looks like you are in control of changing chapter and onclick chapters are displayed. So when chapter is changed set a variable e.g. on `chapter1()`

```
current_chapter = 1
```

Then when images are clicked based on value of `current_chapter` display information related to that chapter.